# Why plugins from lazy nvim are not loaded?

Tags: neovim

I have the `lazy.lua`

```
local lazypath = vim.fn.stdpath("data") .. "/lazy/lazy.nvim"
if not vim.loop.fs_stat(lazypath) then
  vim.fn.system({
    "git",
    "clone",
    "--filter=blob:none",
    "https://github.com/folke/lazy.nvim.git",
    "--branch=stable", -- latest stable release
    lazypath,
  })
end
vim.opt.rtp:prepend(lazypath)

require("lazy").setup(
    {
        'nvim-telescope/telescope.nvim',
        tag = '0.1.5',
        dependencies = { 'nvim-lua/plenary.nvim' }
    },
    { 
        "rose-pine/neovim",
        name = "rose-pine" 
    }
)
```

I've included that `lazy.lua` to the `init.lua`

for some reason, when I use `:Lazy` I can see that only telescope has been installed, but rose-pine theme not.

And `:message` don't show any error messages